# Parent window says variable is undefined, but child window has vaules

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript issue and I'm very puzzled by it. I can't seem to figure out why one function is returning an array (Which it is an array) but another function is returning undefined.

Issue: Why is one function returning an array but the other is returning undefined in the parent window?

So with some background I have a javascript child that is sending data back to the parent window. Now it is only sending integers, so nothing too big or problematic. The information is saved in the parent window. The only thing the child window is doing is sending the information back. (Basically saying "Ooh this was selected").

Child window

```
    else{
            if(document.getElementById("embroid"+embroideryID).checked == false){
                    parent.EmbroideryDataReturned("add", embroideryID);
                    document.getElementById("embroid"+embroideryID).checked = true;
            }
            else{
                    parent.EmbroideryDataReturned("remove", embroideryID);
                    document.getElementById("embroid"+embroideryID).checked = false;
            }
    }

function SelectedEmbroideries(){
    var embroideries = parent.EmbroideryDataReturned("get", 0);

    for(i  = 0; i < embroideries.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("embroid"+embroideries[i]).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Parent Window

```
var embroidArray = new Array();
function EmbroideryDataReturned(mode, embroidID){
    if(mode == 'add'){
            embroidArray.push(embroidID);
            //alert(mode + " " + embroidID + " Array is now: \n"+ embroidArray);
            return;
    }
    else if(mode == 'remove'){
            embroidArray.splice(embroidArray.indexOf(embroidID), 1);
            //alert(mode + " " + embroidID + " Array is now: \n"+ embroidArray);
            return;
    }
    else if(mode = 'get'){
            return embroidArray;
    }
}
```

The parent window, in the alerts, correctly display the array. However when it goes to run the update that function says the value is undefined. What is causing this issue?

Comment: It should be `parent.window.EmbroideryDataReturned`

Comment: Also the last `if` statement in that function has a `=` where it should (probably) have `==` or `===`.

Comment: @adeneo Appreciated, but it doesn't really do anything. Although I do understand why you said it =). Pointy, Thank you! I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out there was a parameter that was being passed through as the same name as the variable I was trying to use. So my mistake! Thanks for the help though!